# Scrollify + custom scroll events

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

Essentially, I need scrollify to stop running once it gets to the first section, then start running again once the first section's animations are complete. I have tried stop(); but with no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() {
$('.section-image1').hide();
$('.section-image2').hide();
$('.section-image3').hide();
$.scrollify({
    section: ".header-home",
    section: ".section",
    before: function(section){
        console.log(section);
        if(section==1){
            //stop scrollify
            $(window).scroll(function(){

                $('.section-image1').show();
                $('.section-image2').show();
                $('.section-image3').show();
                $('.section-image1').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.section-image2').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.section-image3').addClass('fadeInUp');
        });
            //start scrollify
            if(section==2){
            //stop scrollify
            $(window).scroll(function(){

                $('.section-image4').show();
                $('.section-image5').show();
                $('.section-image6').show();
                $('.section-image4').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.section-image5').addClass('fadeInUp');
                $('.section-image6').addClass('fadeInUp');
        });
    }

}
});
});
```

Comment: Why do you need the `$(window).scroll` events?

Comment: I was trying to add an 'on.scroll' event so that I could scroll for my animations

Comment: Scrollify's `after` callback is called whenever you scroll to a new sections. There should not be a need to add your own scroll events.